# is there a way to query vsts to select the target framework version for a collection of projects?

Tags: c#, .net, git, azure-devops

Is there a way to query vsts to determine the set of target framework versions for a collection of projects?  For example, let's use the following collection of projects as an example:

- https://my-corp.visualstudio.com/a-team/_git/my-proj-1
- https://my-corp.visualstudio.com/a-team/_git/my-proj-2
- https://my-corp.visualstudio.com/a-team/_git/my-proj-3

Does VSTS support any type of ability to write a query along the lines of something like this?:

```
var baseUrl = "https://my-corp.visualstudio.com";
var qo = new QueryObject(baseUrl);
var projects = new string[]
{
"a-team/_git/my-proj-1",
"a-team/_git/my-proj-2",
"a-team/_git/my-proj-3",
};
var targetFWVersions = new List<string>()
foreach(var csproj in qo.SelectFile(".csproj"))
   targetFWVersions.Add(csproj.SelectInnerXml("TargetFrameworkVersion"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Code Search](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms.vss-code-search) to search within files in source control. You can also use the [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/search/code%20search%20results/fetch%20code%20search%20results?view=vsts-rest-4.1)s to programatically run a code search and retrieve the results.

Comment: thanks daniel.  I made my first attempt to use the vsts rest api but the implementation is returning a 404 without a detailed error message.  I posted a separate thread with example code here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50724808/why-is-this-vsts-rest-api-returning-404

Comment: @user9393635 What's the result if you search within files in source control directly?