# why is this vsts rest api returning 404?

Tags: c#, .net, git, azure-devops

I was following this example to use the VSTS REST API:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/search/code%20search%20results/fetch%20code%20search%20results?view=vsts-rest-4.1

The following url points directly to MyService.MyController in my org's VSTS:

https://my-corp.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/USOpsInfrastructure/USOpsInfrastructure%20Team/_git/MyService?path=%2FMyService.UI%2FControllers%2FMyController.cs&version=GBmaster

I tried to follow the example code with my implentation code below but a 404 response is returned without a detailed message.  Any idea what the issue might be or how to debug?

```
private static async Task FindMyControllerRefs()
{
    var baseUrl = "https://my-corp.almsearch.visualstudio.com";
    using (var client = GetHttpClient(baseUrl))
    {
        var request = "{ \"searchText\": \"MyController\" }";
        var projectUri = "/USOpsInfrastructure/USOpsInfrastructure%20Team/_git/MyService";
        var searchUri = "/_apis/search/codesearchresults?api-version=4.1-preview.1";
        var fullUri = projectUri + searchUri;
        var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(fullUri, request);

        //process the response
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var result = (await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<string>());
        }
        else //not 200
        {
            var message = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
    }
}

private static HttpClient GetHttpClient(string baseUrl)
{
    var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { UseDefaultCredentials = true });
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl);
    client.Timeout = Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan;
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
        new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    return client;
}
```

Comment: Do you have the code search extension installed?

Comment: Also, the URL is wrong. Based on the REST API example from the documentation, it should be `https://my-corp.almsearch.visualstudio.com/USOpsInfrastructure//_apis/search/codesearchresults?api-version=4.1-preview.1`. You need to include the project in the URL.

Comment: @daniel the name of the project is "MyService" and it's included at the end of the projectUri variable in my sample code above: "/USOpsInfrastructure/USOpsInfrastructure%20Team/_git/MyService".  The 2 path levels before the project indicate the project's relative location in VSTS.  In my code, you can see that I'm passing the project name as part of the fullUri variable.  Looks like the url you posted in your comment may not have been posted completely so I'm not sue what I'm missing here?

Comment: No, that's the **repository**. When I'm talking about 'project', I'm talking about the name of the **team project**. `USOpsInfrastructure` appears to be the name of the team project.

Answer (score 1):

The Code search REST API should be :

```
POST https://XXX.almsearch.visualstudio.com/{Project}/_apis/search/codesearchresults?api-version=4.1-preview.1
```

In you scenario please confirm what's the team project name: `USOpsInfrastructure` or `MyService`. If you are not sure about that, then you can have a try for each of them.

Besides, base on my  test you need to add the `"$top": 10` (you can change the number as needed) in the request body:

```
var request = "{ \"searchText\": \"MyController\",\"$top\": 10 }";
```

Below code works on my side: (Project name is "**Git**" in below sample)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CodeSearch
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Task t = CodeSearch();
            Task.WaitAll(new Task[] { t });
        }
        private static async Task CodeSearch()
        {
            try
            {
                var username = "username";
                var password = "Password/PAT";

                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                        new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic",
                        Convert.ToBase64String(
                            System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
                                string.Format("{0}:{1}", username, password))));

                    string url = "https://{instance}.almsearch.visualstudio.com/Git/_apis/search/codesearchresults?api-version=4.1-preview.1";
                    var content = new StringContent("{\"searchText\": \"OwinStartupAttribute\",  \"$top\": 10}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                    using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync(url, content).Result)
                    {
                        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                        string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        Console.WriteLine(responseBody);

                    }
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: @user9393635 Have you resolved the issue? any update?